# remove Outlook from taskbar *when maximized* (not minimized)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, taskbar

I have Outlook 2010 constantly displayed on a monitor (dual monitors, Windows 7) and I am wondering if there would be a way to remove the taskbar button (taskbar, not notification area) so that it does not take space (I could then access it either directly or via the icon in the notification area).

I know about the "hide when minimized" feature but in my case Outlook is always maximized. I am looking, so to speak, for a "hide when maximized" option.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know no such thing exists right now, you would need to write a plugin/application that hooks into application start, a wrapper that denies Windows from seeing Outlook as an application, or one that can modify your taskbar, but I'm not sure how that would work correclty. The closest I think you can get is move away the Icon from the current monitor by using dual monitor taskbars (google them) and move the icon to the second screen.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. EDIT: I thought that the second taskbar would take valuable space but http://dualmonitortb.sourceforge.net/ works perfectly with auto-hide mode. Adopted :)